# NuGet pack "The DateTimeOffset specified cannot be converted into a Zip file timestamp"

Tags: c#, nuget, dotnet-cli

When I want to pack my library as a NuGet package, I get the below error

**The DateTimeOffset specified cannot be converted into a Zip file timestamp**

I'm using the below command to pack my project:

```
dotnet msbuild /t:pack /p:Configuration=Release /p:SourceLinkCreate=true
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is; some DLL files have invalid dates for a zip file (like 31/12/1979).
You can overcome this issue by updating all the invalid DLL files modification date.
Here's the Powershell script that updates all the invalid DLLs.

```
gci -path "C:\" -rec -file *.dll | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddYears(-20)} | %  { try { $_.LastWriteTime = '01/01/2020 00:00:00' } catch {} }
```

It sets all the invalid DLL dates to `01/01/2000`.
Change the `path` parameter for your computer.
My GitHub repositories are on my `C` drive so I'm running this `-path C:\`.

Comment: this doesn't harm anything on your computer. it filters only the DLLs with the modification date is set 20 years ago. so you can run this PowerShell script multiple times without any issues.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how did you end up with dll with last write time from 1979?

Comment: Some Microsoft DLLs are timestamped with 31/12/1979. I don't know the reason why it's so. Some CI/CD pipelines of Microsoft I guess. See https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7001

Answer (score 3):

Seems that in most of cases (basing on research in github issues) the problem was related to `Microsoft.Extensions.*` packages. In my case update to newer version of `Microsoft.Extensions.*` (from 3.1.0 to 3.1.4) fixed the problem. For reference :

https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2750

and mentioned in comments :

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7001

Comment: But what can you do if it's a downstream dependency of another package you're using?

Answer (score 2):

I made a console app to fix invalid dates in a drive (cross-platform). It sets the LastModificationDate to 01/01/2000. You can just run it without any arguments. It will run in all your drives. Also you can specify a directory to search in.

**Source-code on GitHub**:

- https://github.com/ebicoglu/FileBulkDateChanger

**Usage:**

```
FileBulkDateChanger.exe
```

or

```
FileBulkDateChanger.exe C:\
```

For MAC/Linux,

```
dotnet FileBulkDateChanger.dll
```

Run this tool and forget about this issue :)